Canon MP560 seemingly “skipping” print lines
I’m desperately trying to revive my MP560- & I’ve done everything I can think of or find to resolve it! I’ve deep cleaned the head and even took it out to manually do so, made sure there were air holes in the new ink(I’ve swapped them twice to no avail) and there are 0 other issues and absolutely no errors etc. I’ve attached the most recent Nozzle Check Pattern for reference, as it to me implies it is not a nozzle or head issue. Is it a system/ setting or driver issue? Can it be resolved?!? They are in the exact same place each time.


This question is similar to: Printer prints perfect horizontal white lines. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't see how this could be a system/setting or driver issue. However, you could try to reset the printer back to its default settings as a first try:
https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/s/article/ART131905
Setting the MP560 back to default settings:

Press the  button.
Use the Easy-Scroll Wheel or the right / left arrow to select
[Settings], then press the  button.
Use the Easy-Scroll Wheel or the right / left arrow to select
[Device settings], then press the  button.
Use the Easy-Scroll Wheel or the up / down arrow to select [Reset
settings], then press the  button.
Use the Easy-Scroll wheel or the up / down arrow to select [Yes] on
the confirmation screen and then press .

If that doesn't work then most likely it's the head of the unit - still clogged. Found this video that shows to use hot water which might better dislodge any dried or solidified ink:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UaVgjdyhwdw
Remove the ink cartridges from the head of the printer, then remove the head from the printer slot. Run the head under hot water for as long as no ink comes out any more on both sides of the head - the reservoir area as well as the output panel on the other side. Just make sure the head is thoroughly dried before putting it back into the unit, can use a blow dryer (not up close) to the head to dry it faster. Put back in the ink cartridges. Then do another Nozzle Check Pattern to see if that has resolved the issue.

Including the steps from the support article here would improve this. We do require that all instructions for a fix be in the answer here, and links only necessary for attribution and further research, if necessary. This allows your answer to continue being relevant and helpful even if the link dies. Please EDIT your answer to include that information here.
